# Remove table name prefix in EF code first foreign key table column

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I have two Entities:

```
Room{
    [Key]
    public int RoomID {get;set;}
    public String RoomName {get;set;}
    public List<Member> ListMember {get;set;}
}

Member {
    [Key]
    public int MemberID {get;set;}
    public String MemberName {get;set;}
    public Room Room {get;set;}
}
```

when generate the database, table Member look like:

```
Member(
    MemberID int,
    MemberName nvarchar.
    Room_RoomID int   //references to Room(RoomID)
)
```

I want the foreign key column have name `RoomID`   (same as Room's original name) instead of `(Room_RoomID)` .
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options to do that:

1. Declare that `RoomId` FK property in the `Member` entity and use
   the `ForeignKey` data annotation:

   ```
   public classMember {
       [Key]
       public int MemberID {get;set;}
       public String MemberName {get;set;}

       [ForeignKey("Room")]
       public int RoomID {get;set;}
       public Room Room {get;set;}
   }
   ```

   Code First convention creates a column name same as the property name.
2. If you don't want to declare the `RoomId` FK property in your `Member` entity, you can override `OnModelCreating` method in your context class to
   configure your relationship and specify the FK name using the
   `MapKey` method:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasRequired(m=>m.Room).WithMany(r=>r.ListMember).Map(a => a.MapKey("RoomId")) 
   }
   ```

Now, in case that you declare the `RoomId` FK property but you want to change the name of that column in your `Members` table , you can use the [Column](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) data annotation.